Panoply doesn't allow export
I'm trying to export from Panoply to CSV. I right click > export to CSV but nothing saves in the correct folder. Actually, there's no format that allows me to save that way. Any advice for why this might be? I can open, visualise and plot data in panoply fine.... just not export.

Same here, just downloaded the latest .tar.gz for Linux and I get a save dialog that lets me choose a folder and file to save as but click "OK" and the dialog goes but no file appears. Same with save as CDL and tagged data (or whatever the other save options are). Either a bug or an incompatibility with installed Java versions...

There have been a couple Panoply releases since OP posted. Is this still happening?

Thanks for letting me know -- yes! this works now (tried 5.4.1 Mac)
